# ecto jsonb array and map cast issue

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, jsonb

I want to store data using jsonb that could be either an array or a map. The source data arrives as either an array or a map, and we want to unify this on the server so the front-end can work with a single type. Is there a way/workaround that I can use, store and retrieve both json/map and array types which are valid for the jsonb postgres type?

I have tried to use `source:` to copy to array type `sourced` field before calling cast pipeline if I get an array in `params`:

```elixir
condition: Map.has_key?(params, "value") && is_list(value)
```

I am successfully able to save data, but when retrieving from the DB I am getting a cast error

```elixir
field(:value, :map)
field(:value_array, {:array, :integer}, source: :value)
```

Note: Ecto version > 3 and postgres 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to define [custom ecto types](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html) which would accept and load both arrays and maps

```elixir
defmodule HaiData.Jsonb do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type
  def type, do: :map

  # Provide custom casting rules.
  def cast(data) when is_list(data) or is_map(data) do
    {:ok, data}
  end


  # Everything else is a failure though
  def cast(_), do: :error

  # When loading data from the database, we are guaranteed to
  # receive a map or list
  def load(data) when is_list(data) or is_map(data) do
    {:ok, data}
  end

  # When dumping data to the database, we *expect* a map or list
  # so we need to guard against them.
  def dump(data)  when is_list(data) or is_map(data), do: {:ok, data}
  def dump(_), do: :error
end
```

Credit goes to [idiot - an elixirforum user](https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-jsonb-postgres-issue/21491/3?u=tanweerdev)